# Template class with template method id

Tags: c++, templates, vivado-hls

I am trying to create an identifier for my methods. This identifier is important for my work as it is in fact hardware synthesis.

I have the following template class:

```
        template <int FF_COUNT, int FB_COUNT, int NEXT_COUNT>
        class Core{
        public:
        ...
            template<int id> void consume_fb_events (hls::stream<event>  feedback_stream [FB_COUNT] [FB_COUNT], weight w_mem [128*128]);
        }
    


template <int FF_COUNT, int FB_COUNT, int NEXT_COUNT>
    template <int id>
    void Core<FF_COUNT, FB_COUNT, NEXT_COUNT>::consume_fb_events (hls::stream<event> feedback_stream [FB_COUNT] [FB_COUNT], weight w_mem [128*128]){
    #pragma HLS INLINE off
    event e;   
            for(int i = 0 ; i < FB_COUNT ; i++) {
                while (!feedback_stream[id][i].empty()) {
                    feedback_stream[id][i].read(e);
                    ap_uint<16> mem_offset = e << size_exp;
                    consume_event (e, mem_offset, w_mem);    
            }
    }
    }
```

and this is my function call

```
    #define sth 8
for int i = 0 ; i < sth; i++
    core[i].consume_fb_events<i>(....);
```

I get the compilation error:

```
ERROR: [HLS 200-70] Compilation errors found: In file included from c1/srnn.cpp:1:
c1/srnn.cpp:197:14: error: no matching member function for call to 'consume_fb_events'
   core_1[i].consume_fb_events<i>(buffer_layer1_1, w1[i]);
   ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c1/core.h:52:24: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'id'
 template<int id> void consume_fb_events (hls::stream<event> feedback_stream [FB_COUNT] [FB_COUNT], weight w_mem [128*128]);
                   ^
```

Comment: You can't use `i` as template parameter, since it's not known at compile time. Why not just make it a normal parameter?

Comment: Making it a normal parameter means it is unknown at compile time. I need it known for my hardware synthesis.

Comment: Is `sth` known at compile time? If so, you need a _constexpr_ kind-of-loop - if it's not known, neither can `i` be.

Comment: Yes, sth is indeed a constant value. Could you please tell me how to specify so?

Comment: It is defined as so:
#define C1_UNROLL 8
for (int i = 0 ; i < C1_UNROLL; i++) core[i].consume_fb_events<i>(...)

Comment: If `sth` constant and as low as 8 I would just manually unroll the loop and explicitly write all 8 lines. You could probably write a recursive `constexpr` function for this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your looking for is a for loop at compile time. Because the template parameter must be a constexpr. I usually do it this way since you can't have for loops in constexpr functions:

```
template<int i>
struct MyFunc
{
    MyFunc()
    {
        // do something with i
        core[i].consume_fb_events<i>(....);
    }
};

template<int end, template <int I> class func, int i = 0>
struct ForLoop
{
    ForLoop()
    {
        func<i>{};
        ForLoop<end, func, i+1>{};
    }
};

template<int end, template <int I> class func>
struct ForLoop<end, func, end>
{
    ForLoop()
    {
    }
};
```

You can run any code in the constructor of `MyFunc`.

You can then execute it like that:

```
ForLoop<8, MyFunc>{};
```

where 8 is the number you would usually but at the `i < ...` part of the for loop

You have to be careful with this, because this will only work for `end` up to about 900 (depending on the max template recursion depth). Or else you will get a compile time error.

[live example with std::cout](https://onlinegdb.com/FQU_3_Mb9)

**EDIT:**

---

Since @SherifBadawy asked in a comment, you don't have to declare a struct/class `MyFunc` to do this, but I went with this approach because it makes the `ForLoop` more dynamic and you can reuse it multiple times.

But if you'd like to this would also work:

```
template<int i>
void foo()
{
    // code here
}

template<int end, int i = 0>
struct ForLoop
{
    ForLoop()
    {
        core[i].consume_fb_events<i>(....);
        // more code

        // or ...

        foo<i>();

        ForLoop<end, func, i+1>{};
    }
};

template<int end>
struct ForLoop<end, end>
{
    ForLoop()
    {
    }
};
```

To run `ForLoop` you would again do:

```
ForLoop<8>{}; // without passing a class or function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Could you please recheck for typos? What is func<i>{};? Did you mean MyFunc<i>?

Comment: template <int FF_COUNT, int FB_COUNT, int NEXT_COUNT>
class Core{
public: 
template<int id>
 struct consume_function {
  void consume_ff_events <id> (hls::stream<event> input_stream [FB_COUNT] [FF_COUNT]  , weight w_mem [128 * 128]);
  void consume_fb_events <id>(hls::stream<event> feedback_stream [FB_COUNT] [FB_COUNT], weight w_mem [128*128]){

 };
This is how im implementing it so far...is it right?

Comment: @SherifBadawy No, `func` is the template parameter, it's used kinda like a lambda but you can also directly call `MyFunc` if you wanted to. With the template parameter it gets more dynamic and reusable.

Comment: @SherifBadawy Should be, of course you can also use a templated function instead of a class constructor in the constructor of `ForLoop`

Comment: So I dont need struct "consume function"? I can just have the normal template function declaration, and instead call the function in in the constructor of ForLoop?

Comment: @SherifBadawy Yes. just as a reminder if my answer solved your question could you please mark it as Solution.

Comment: Ofcourse! If you may, could you please tell me if it is possible to pass some parameters in the call in the main function (ForLoop<8>{} to pass the arguments of consume_ff_events

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238435/discussion-between-gian-laager-and-sherif-badawy).